# Getting the Chip Name of sensors being used in Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I need to modify some sensors driver code in the Android linux kernel. I am able to get the logical name of sensors present in the phone from getevent or "sys" file system like "gyro","lighsenors" etc. But how can I get the actual chip name of sensors like (mxt224_ts) which maps to these logical names.

When I looked in linux driver directory, I found that it has separate files for each chip but many chip can implement the functionality for single sensor. Therefore I am unable to identify the actual file which is being used in the device(phone).

Answer (score 0):

The sysfs directory has an entry named `name`.